# Overwriting a field's method in Python

Tags: python, oop, overwrite

I have a custom class which I instantiate twice in a second class:

[EDIT: The old code wasn't really capturing what my issue is, I'm rewriting to make it clearer. Foo is going to process network events (and I need multiple connections, hence why Bar will have multiple Foo fields and can't just inherit) by using a callback function. In the Bar class, i want to overwrite the callback to do something different. Rewriting callb in Foo won't work, because I do inherit from it in other instances]

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x
        #When an event happens, call callb()
        self.on_certain_event(callback=callb)

    def callb(self):
        print self._x

    def run(self):
        waitForEventsInfinitely() #

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._foo = Foo(5)
        #OVERWRITE THE EXISTING CALLBACK METHOD IN THE Foo CLASS!
        self._foo.callb = self.callb

    def callb(self):
        print self._x * 10

    def run(self):
        waitForEventsInfinitely() # Not going to actually write t

f = Foo(2)
f.run()
b = Bar()
b.run()
```

[When run() is called in a Foo, it works correctly. However, I cannot overwrite the callb method of Foo from Bar - the self._x which should be referred to by Foo is trying to call from Bar]

However, when running the code, I receive the error "Bar has no attribute '_x'" rather than my expected value of 50. Obviously, the self in Bar's test is still referring to Bar, not the Foo which is actually calling the method. I would have expected it to be the internal Foo self._foo field in Bar.

I suspect my problem has something to do with name mangling, but I haven't been able to find a descriptive source when I have fields on self having their methods overwritten. Most examples seem to be when I'm inheriting from a different class.

Comment: I think you might want `print self._foo._x * 10`

Comment: If you are "overwriting methods" then why would you not just inherit `Foo` from `Bar`?  It seems like you're trying to simulate inheritance -- why not just *use inheritance?*

Comment: Is that `__init` or `__init__`?

Comment: @cdhowie Because in my actual code I'm going to have multiple instances of Foo in one bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok short lesson on how classes in Python work: Any function stored on a class object (a "method") is automatically fetched by a [descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object) (which describes how to getl attributes from objects) that binds the methods to the class or instance you used to get it.

For example:

```
Foo.test
```

is a **unbound method of class Foo**: This is a object created by the descriptor on `Foo` that knows it was fetched from a class object

```
Foo().test
```

is a **bound method of a instance of class Foo**: This method stores the instance of `Foo` used to fetch the function. This instance is automatically passed as the first argument when you call the resulting object and that's why you write `self` as the first parameter when you define a method.

So, what you are trying to do is this:

1. Get the *raw* function `test` from class `Bar` (not through a descriptor)
2. Bind this function to a instance of `Foo`
3. Store this function on the foo instance

So, this is how you do it:

```
import types 

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._foo = Foo(5)

        raw_function = Bar.test_Bar.__func__                        # 1)
        bound_to_foo = types.MethodType(raw_function, self._foo)    # 2)    
        self._foo.test = bound_to_foo                               # 3)

    def test(self):
        print self._x * 10
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object) for more details on descriptors.

Comment: Awesome - this is exactly what I was after. I'll do a little more testing to confirm but I'm preemptively marking as correct based on the first one.

Comment: While this is true, and a neat hack, functions are first class objects, so why not just pass a value and a function into Foo in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that in Bar.test you want :

```
print self._foo._x * 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your code, when you call b.test, you are calling the method directly on an instance of Bar; no instance of Foo is mentioned at all. b doesn't have a member named _x, hence the error. To get the behaviour you expect, you must call b._foo.test. This will give you your expected result of 50.

If you want to be able to call b.test directly, change self._x to self._foo._x. This way you don't have to change any methods of _foo. I'm not really sure why you would assign different methods to an object when you could use inheritance anyway.